# How to Customize the Zipkin message publisher?

Tags: zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have created a spring-boot application which publishes zipkin logs to a zipkin consumer. But the Zipkin consumer(another spring boot application) is behind some authentication filters which check for several parameters/headers in the request before allowing. How to I use my own custom HttpClient to publish my messages from the producer in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to implement your own ZipkinSpanReporter that would look more or less like https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v1.0.8.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin/HttpZipkinSpanReporter.java . In the next version of Sleuth you will be able to register a bean of ZipkinSpanReporter that can you a custom version of a publisher - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/1.0.x/spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/zipkin/HttpZipkinSpanReporter.java

Comment: How do I register my CustomHttpZipkinSpanReporter with Zipkin reporter?

Comment: It's a Spring bean. Just create your own